# GitHub Actions restrict job with tag validation using if condition or github ref

Tags: maven, github, conditional-statements, github-actions, workflow

I have an application code which runs the maven builds we created snapshots and then create a tag created once the snapshot build is successful, and then we use the tag created in the snapshot build and then run the build using the tag for release using the GitHub actions workflows.
now I'm trying to run the release of the build workflow job only if the tag as matching and if the tag, not matches, skip the jobs or fails the jobs, let's say the tag will be created in the snapshot build and will use tag format as `"<appname>-<app_build_type>-<github-actions-run_number>-<env>-origin/<branch>"` and the actual tag looks like `"java-maven-44-dev-origin/develop"`
I was trying the below 2 methods workflows, but it is not at all working
**1st Method is:**

```
name: maven-release

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  checkout_code:
    runs-on: [ubuntu-latest]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

  maven_build:
    runs-on: [ubuntu-latest]
    if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/tags/*-origin/develop' }}
    needs: checkout_code
    steps:
      - name: Run maven build
        run: |
          mvn clean install
```

**2nd Method is:**

```
name: maven-release

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  checkout_code:
    runs-on: [ubuntu-latest]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

  maven_build:
    runs-on: [ubuntu-latest]
    if: contains(github.ref, 'refs/tags/*-origin/develop')
    needs: checkout_code
    steps:
      - name: Run maven build
        run: |
          mvn clean install
```

I want to skip/fail the at job level only and no in run command, if anyone knows any solution to this or anyone can provide some suggestions on how to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the workflows for which each task needs to be executed only on a particular tag, then we can make use of below snipped

```
name: maven_build
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  checkout:
    runs-on: [ubuntu-latest]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
  maven_build:
    runs-on: [ubuntu-latest]
    if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/') && !contains(github.ref')
    needs: checkout
    steps:
      - name: Run maven build command
        run: |
          mvn clean install
```

The above snippet will run only when the checkout branch matches a tag

Answer (score 0):

Its it's possible for your use case, you could trigger your workflow on push and then apply your filter to the branch or tag

```
name: maven-release

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    tags:
      - '*-origin/develop'

jobs:
  checkout_code:
    runs-on: [ubuntu-latest]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

  maven_build:
    runs-on: [ubuntu-latest]
    if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/tags/*-origin/develop' }}
    needs: checkout_code
    steps:
      - name: Run maven build
        run: |
          mvn clean install
```

The Github [filter pattern cheat sheet](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#filter-pattern-cheat-sheet)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have a question when we use push in workflow_dispatch like the below code, will it be triggered when a new tag is created right or else when we manually triggered it will validate the tag which we have selected during the workflow run like "tag selected in use workflow from"?
```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    tags:
      - '*-origin/develop'
```
I want to run the workflows manually and should not trigger when we push the code to tag or a new tag got created

Comment: `push` and `workflow_dispatch` are independent. They are different ways the workflow can trigger.  The filter I used with the push trigger does't apply to workflow_dispatch. If you need to trigger it manually then your 2nd Method would be the best way to check for the tag on that job. Your first method won't work because the if statement checks the exact literal string value and doesn't allow for a * wildcard.